# Unable to Mock DynamoDB Mapper on jenkins using Mockito

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, mockito

I tried mocking DynamoDBMapper from amazon aws(com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper) using mockito. This works fine on my local machine but I get the following error when I run it on jenkins

"Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper"

Following is the Java and OS versions I have on jenkins

1. Java               : 1.8
2. JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation JVM
3. vendor version : 25.5-b02
4. JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM)64-Bit Server VM
5. JVM version        : 1.8.0_05-b13
6. JVM info           : mixed mode
7. OS name            : Linux
8. OS version         : 4.9.85-37.55.amzn1.x86_64

Following is the code I am using to mock Dynamodb mapper

```
@Mock
private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    initMocks(this);
    repository = new DynamoDBReservationStateRepositoryImpl();
    repository.setDynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBMapper);
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why I have different behavior on my local machine and jenkins and how I can fix this issue without adding any additional wrapper around DynamoDBMapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to jdk version.